# stream_socket_client fails from browser but works for command line

Tags: php, ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, stream-socket-client

I am working on iOS based push notifications. My code works perfectly fine when using say sendpush.php script and run it as $php sendpush.php from command line. But when I run same script from browser or say phone, it doesn't send push notification. I have verified that deviceToken is getting set properly. The error is coming when I am trying to connect using : stream_socket_client.

Anyone faced similar problem. Could it be due to permissions ? because the user from browser and terminal are different ?